# CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH Error

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, node

I am trying to run my own cardano node and use cli wallets. When I run this command: cardano-cli query tip --mainnet

I am getting the following error: Command failed: query tip  Error: Error while looking up environment variable: CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH  Error: "CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH"

Can some one guide me please? I am very new to this

Thanks a Ton

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you forgot to set the environment variable for CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH as mentioned in here while setting up the node.

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano/#querying-the-cardano-blockchain

Comment: I am now getting this error :(

Comment: root@vmi828826:/home/cardano# cardano-node run \
>    --topology path/to/mainnet-topology.json \
>    --database-path path/to/db \
>    --socket-path path/to/db/node.socket \
>    --host-addr 154.53.34.181 \
>    --port 3001 \
>    --config path/to/mainnet-config.json
InvalidYaml (Just (YamlException "Yaml file not found: path/to/mainnet-config.json"))

cardano-node: YAML exception:
Yaml file not found: path/to/mainnet-config.jsonroot@vmi828826:/home/cardano#

Comment: You have to change each of the values of 'path/to/...' to the actual path that suits your environment.

Comment: damn. i have no idea how to do that lol